# React webpack showing blank page on refresh

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am serving my static files from express and i can see that it loads index.html
But the problem is when on a rout for example localhost:8080/users and i refresh the page, the .css and main.js does not seam to be loaded so it returns blank page.. Any idea on what night be the problem?

My app.js

```
 function App (){
      return (
          <div className="wrapper">
             <Routes>
              {routes.map(({ path, name, Component }, key) => (
                <Route exact path={path} key={key} element={Component} />
              ))}
              </Routes>
          </div>
        );
    }
    
    
    export default App
```

My index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
       <Routes>
       <Route path="*" element={<App />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my webpack:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"); 
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const webpack = require('webpack');
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/../.env'})
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, "/src/Index.js"),
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: 'style-loader!css-loader'
       },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "html-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        APP_API_URL : JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_API_URL)
      },
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "app.css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: process.env.PORT_CLIENT, 
    open: true,
    stats: "errors-only",
  }
};
```

Comment: Check out this finished example using React Router and compare it https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-agqlf5?file=src%2Fmain.jsx

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",

Comment: @Mähnenwolf its nicer syntax, but still the same problem :(

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original comment. I posted a link to a working example, check it out and compare it with your react-router setup.

Comment: I will check it out

Comment: @Mähnenwolf Post an answer so i can give you cred!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this finished example using React Router and compare it with your App.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-agqlf5?file=src%2Fmain.jsx